# How to call an indirect table in FROM

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B'

SELECT * 
FROM CAST('A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8))

SELECT * 
FROM table( CAST('A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8)))

DEFINE tName = CAST('A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8))
SELECT * 
FROM &tName

SET tName AS CAST('A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8))
SELECT * 
FROM &tName

SET @tName AS CAST('A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8))
SELECT * 
FROM @tName

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8)) 
FROM DUAL
)
```

---

(Note: I have also tried adding the owner before the table in all of the examples above, as shown in the second example below)

I have verified that

```
SELECT CAST('A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8)) 
FROM DUAL
```

displays `A170429B`

```
SELECT CAST('owner.A'||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD'))||'B' AS varchar2(8)) 
FROM DUAL
```

displays owner.A170429B

but I can't get the FROM statement to see it as a Table

The database creates a new table every day; which, is why I am trying to do this.

Comment: See Oracle Dynamic SQL https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGIAAF

Comment: You can't supply the table name as a variable or expression, it has to be a fixed value when the statement is parsed. As Serg said you could use dynamic SQL (in PL/SQL) to build the statement at runtime. But you should also reconsider your data model, a new table everyday doesn't sound good.

Comment: "*The database creates a new table every day*" - that sounds like a horrible idea. Why are you doing that? Sounds as if you should be looking into partitioning (Also: the "database" doesn't create any tables - users do).

Comment: @AlexPoole - Partitioning is still a chargeable extra on the Enterprise Edition license. Not every organisation can afford that, even in they need it.

Comment: Sure, which is why I didn't specifically mention it *8-) A single table with an extra date column might work depending on data volumes, even if it can't be partitioned. If not then I've seen a view being redefined each night to include a new table; or a synonym to the latest table could be redefined. I'd prefer either of those to a dynamic query. But not enough info to know what might be appropriate for the OP really.

Answer (score 2):

As others have observed, partitioning is the elegant way to arrange this. But Partitioning remains a licensed extra on the Enterprise Edition,and that's expensive. So here's a couple of cheaper options.

The first option is to do what you are trying to do now, and query each table by name. For this approach to work you need to use dynamic SQL.

Here are some tables - `t170428`, `t170429`, `t170430` - which all look like this

```
create table t170428 (
    id number not null primary key
    , type varchar2(10)
    , col1 varchar2(10)
    , col2 number
    , col3 date not null
    )
/
```

To query them we need a SQL type with a signature that matches the tables' projection:

```
create or replace type tyymmdd_t as object (
    id number 
    , type varchar2(10)
    , col1 varchar2(10)
    , col2 number
    , col3 date
    );
/

create or replace type tyymmdd_nt as table of tyymmdd_t
/
```

Here is a function which dynamic builds a table name from a passed date and returns a nested table of rows from that table:

```
create or replace function get_date_table
    ( p_target_date in date)
    return tyymmdd_nt
is
    return_value tyymmdd_nt;
begin
    execute immediate
        ' select tyymmdd_t(id, type, col1, col2, col3) from t'
           ||to_char(p_target_date, 'yymmdd')
        bulk collect into return_value;
    return return_value;
end;
/
```

To query a table we use the `table()` function like this:

```
SQL> select * from table(get_date_table(sysdate));

        ID TYPE       COL1             COL2 COL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
         9 D2         SUN                 1 30-APR-17
        10 D2         SUN                 2 30-APR-17

SQL> select * from table(get_date_table(date'2017-04-28'));

        ID TYPE       COL1             COL2 COL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
         1 D1         FRI                 1 28-APR-17
         2 D1         FRI                 2 28-APR-17
         3 D1         FRI                 3 28-APR-17
         4 D1         FRI                 4 28-APR-17
         5 D1         FRI                 5 28-APR-17

SQL> select * from table(get_date_table(sysdate+1));
select * from table(get_date_table(sysdate+1))
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "FOX.GET_DATE_TABLE", line 7


SQL>
```

The second option is Partition Views. This is an old technique (from the previous millennium!) which allows us to build a view over multiple tables using the UNION ALL operator and get many benefits of Partitioning such as partition pruning - provided you're using a really old version of Oracle. Partition Views were deprecated in 8.0 and Oracle stopped supporting them in 9iR2. The documentation dates back to Oracle7 [Find out more](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40550/what-is-a-partitioned-view).

Anyway, the principle of partitioned views is this:

- Enforce check constraints on the "partition key"
- Build indexes on the partition key columns
- Gather stats
- Build the view

Like the table projection, the constraints and indexes must be the same for all tables.

```
alter table t170428 add constraint t170428_ptn_key_ck check (col3 = date '2017-04-28');
alter table t170429 add constraint t170429_ptn_key_ck check (col3 = date '2017-04-29');
alter table t170430 add constraint t170430_ptn_key_ck check (col3 = date '2017-04-30');

create unique index t170428_ptn_idx on t170428(col3, id) compress 1;
create unique index t170429_ptn_idx on t170429(col3, id) compress 1;
create unique index t170430_ptn_idx on t170430(col3, id) compress 1;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('FOX', 'T170428', cascade=>true)
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('FOX', 'T170429', cascade=>true)
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('FOX', 'T170430', cascade=>true)

create or replace view v_all_the_dates as
select * from t170428
union all
select * from t170429
union all
select * from t170430
/
```

Because Oracle don't support Partition Views in later versions of the database this approach won't give you partition pruning. But it could still be quite efficient providing you are rigorous about the indexing and check constraints.

A third option which might fit is an external table. The creation of dated tables suggests a daily load. If these just act as staging tables for data which  arrive as files you could use an external table to access the data. The table would be a stable structure; all you would need to change is the location of the daily feed file. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#i1009391).

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is a vended app, and I have read only access to the database. So, I have no control over the way the tables are created or partitioning them. 

I think your answer would work for scenarios where the individual has admin access. 

I have heard that you can somehow create a sub query that Echos the query you need to run, and then create a connection file that uses the Echo.

I am going to research that more, and if not, just use a VBscript to update a .odc file with the new date every day. 

Please let me know if you have any more ideas. Thanks again!

Comment: It seems to me that if a vendor decides to implement such a shonky data architecture they should have the decency to provide a functioning API which encapsulates the shonkiness.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_XMLGEN can create a completely dynamic SQL statement without any additional privileges.

(But before you use the difficult SQL below, I recommend you try again to get more access to the database and use one of APC's solutions.  Write access to the vendor's application schema is not required.  The objects can be created in a separate user schema that will not interfere with the application.)

First, create a test table with today's date in the name

```
begin
    execute immediate '
        create table a'||to_char(sysdate, 'YYMMDD')||'b
        (
            column1 number,
            column2 number
        )';
end;
/
```

Add a test row.  One potential problem with this solution is that when the inner query returns no rows it throw an error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error/nORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272/nORA-06512: at line 1`.

```
begin
    execute immediate 'insert into a'||to_char(sysdate, 'YYMMDD')||'b values (1,2)';
    commit;
end;
/
```

This query reads from the table without knowing the table's name.  It does however require knowing the table's columns.  (If the vendor creates different columns in each table that's a more difficult problem that will definitely require custom objects.)

```
--Step 3: Convert XML back into a row.
select column1, column2
from
(
    --Step 2: Create an XML result set of a dynamic query.
    select
        xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
        (
            --Step 1: SELECT statement that generates a SELECT statement.
            select 
                'select column1, column2
                from a'||to_char(sysdate, 'YYMMDD')||'b'
            from dual
        )
    )) xml_results
    from dual
)
cross join
xmltable
(
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    passing xml_results
    columns
        column1 number path 'COLUMN1',
        column2 number path 'COLUMN2'
);
```

Results:

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2
-------   -------
1               2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I may not have mentioned this, but I am using Excel to pull the information in. For some reason I keep getting errors that it doesn't like the "/" and "begin" symbols. When I take them out I then get syntax errors. You'll have to forgive me, this is my first time doing any major SQL queries to an Oracle database.

I have not been able to get any of these solutions to work. So I switched to plan B and am rewriting the text in the connection file with a VBSCRIPT.

Comment: @Excel_Wiz The first two statements are only for building a test case to demonstrate how this works.  You'll probably want to use a more common Oracle environment for testing, such as SQL Developer or SQL\*Plus.  But you don't need to run them for the real version, just something like the last statement.  But getting the syntax just right depends on your table definition.

Comment: Ok great. I got the spreadsheet to take the query, but did not retrieve any data. Just to verify, is it only step 1 where I replace column1 & column2 with the columns inside the table on the database?

            --Step 1: SELECT statement that generates a SELECT statement.
            select 
                'select column1, column2    <-- do I only need to replace this portion?
                from a'||to_char(sysdate, 'YYMMDD')||'b'
            from dual

Comment: @Excel_Wiz No, unfortunately you need to change 4 places for each column.  The original select list in step 1, the select list in step 3, and twice in the xmltable in step 3.

Comment: select ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE
from
(
    --Step 2: Create an XML result set of a dynamic query.
    select
        xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
        (
            --Step 1: SELECT statement that generates a SELECT statement.
            select 
                'select ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE
                from A'||to_char(sysdate, 'YYMMDD')||'B'
            from dual
        )
    )) xml_results
    from dual
)
cross join
xmltable
(
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    passing xml_results
    columns
        ORDER_ID number path 'COLUMN1',
        ORDER_DATE number path 'COLUMN2'
);

Comment: I changed the column names to be generic for this post, but this is an example of what I have. I do not receive an error, but also do not receive any data. I also tried changing it on the number path, and when I do that I receive an error that the number path is invalid.

Comment: @Excel_Wiz Don't forget to also change the paths from `'COLUMNX'` to `'ORDER_ID'` and `'ORDER_DATE'`.  To help visualize what's going on in the query try running just step 1, and then step 2, to see the XML output before it's processed back into rows.

Comment: It keeps saying number path is invalid when I do that.

Comment: Try changing `number` to `varchar2(4000)`.  Eventually you'll probably want to get it as a date but for now a varchar2 should be easier to get working.